# Size of cones in 3d animated cone plot with variable animation speed

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

The docstring of the property `sizeref` in `plotly.graph_objs._cone.py` says:

```
        Adjusts the cone size scaling. The size of the cones is
        determined by their u/v/w norm multiplied a factor and
        `sizeref`. This factor (computed internally) corresponds to the
        minimum "time" to travel across two successive x/y/z positions
        at the average velocity of those two successive positions. All
        cones in a given trace use the same factor. With `sizemode` set
        to "scaled", `sizeref` is unitless, its default value is 0.5
        With `sizemode` set to "absolute", `sizeref` has the same units
        as the u/v/w vector field, its the default value is half the
        sample's maximum vector norm.

        The 'sizeref' property is a number and may be specified as:
          - An int or float in the interval [0, inf]

        Returns
        -------
        int|float
```

where there is this mysterious factor that is computed  and for the life of me I cannot find where it is actually computed. Since I do not understand how this weird factor is computed I get very strange behaviour in my animations as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as pl

###np.around used because plotly.js doesn't like full precision float64s
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
x = np.around(np.vstack((np.cos(t), np.cos(t+np.pi))),decimals=6)
y = np.around(np.vstack((np.sin(t), np.sin(t+np.pi))),decimals=6)
z = np.around(np.vstack((np.ones(len(t)),np.ones(len(t)))),decimals=6)

v = np.around(np.vstack((np.cos(t), np.cos(t+np.pi))),decimals=6)
u = np.around(-np.vstack((np.sin(t), np.sin(t+np.pi))),decimals=6)
w = np.around(np.vstack((np.zeros(len(t)),np.ones(len(t)))),decimals=6)

fig3=go.Figure([dict(anchor="cm",showscale=False,sizemode="scaled",type="cone",x=x[:,0],y=y[:,0]
                                        ,z=z[:,0]
                                        ,u=u[:,0],v=v[:,0]
                                        ,w=w[:,0])],layout=go.Layout(
    scene=dict(aspectratio=dict(x=1,y=1,z=0.25),
                    xaxis=dict(range=[-2,2], tickmode="linear"),
                    yaxis=dict(range=[-2,2], tickmode="linear"),
                    zaxis=dict(range=[0,5]))))

fig3.frames= [go.Frame(data=[dict(type="cone",x=x[:,i],y=y[:,i],z=z[:,i],u=u[:,i],v=v[:,i],w=w[:,i])], 
                             layout=go.Layout(annotations=[dict(text="frame {}".format(i))]))for i in np.array(range(len(t)))]

pl.plot(fig3, animation_opts="{frame: {duration: 1}}")
```

Note that you must first either remove the `animation_opts` kwarg or use plotly from [my repo](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1496) since the official version doesn't support animation_opts yet ([see the issue I raised here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1496)).

[image: The plot that results from the above code (haven't figured out how to convert to video format yet!)]

Where is this factor calculated? I have scoured the code but found nothing.
Thanks in advance!

P.S Yes I included a lot of extraneous information. I have never seen an example of 3d cone animations in plotly yet so I wanted to provide one and I worked on the animation interface in plotly.py which will definitely be useful to someone!

EDIT: see this [issue on github](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3613)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out there was an internal scaling factor in Plotly.js that was causing this mess. I have fixed this in my current repo version of plotly [here](https://github.com/TakodaS/plotly.py).

Comment: What the factor tho?